# Issues with model binding array of ViewModels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, model-binding

I am sending a model to my back end server via an axios.post request. All good. However, I struggle to send an array of these ViewModels.

This is what I've got so far.

My axios method:

```
 createMusicList() {
         const { playlist } = this.state;

         let model = {Name: "PlayListOne",
            Tracks: ["test1", "test2"]}

         console.log(playlist);
         console.log(model);


        axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:60231/api/values',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'content-type' : 'application.json'},
            params: model
            })       
        .then(function (response){
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        });
     }
```

Here is my ViewModel on my back end:

```
public class PlaylistModel
    {
        public string[] Tracks { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my ActionMethod on my back end:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void Post(PlaylistModel result)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Is this the correct way to proceed with passing down arrays as well? Should I make all of my properties in my ViewModel of type arrays if I am passing multiple objects with these propierties?

**EDIT:** I changed the code for simplicity and for testing purposes. If I send in "model" to the BackEnd, the "Name" property is mapped, however, the array of strings is not - it returns something like {string[0]}

Comment: I can’t wrap my head around, why are u sending array?

Comment: @ShivamSood I want to send many objects at once to the database to be saved. Thats why.

Comment: How will u be able to send many object if u are using [0] index as `playlist[0].Name` will always send first value in array to ur backend saving same items again and again. 

Are u getting this value from users Input?

Comment: I know, my mistake. Still didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you are getting data correctly in `model` variable. Couple of things that IMO are messed up 1) Content-type should be `application/Json` 2) send `model` in as `data` instead of `params` like `data:model`

Comment: It works with params. The problem is with the collecions: they can not be binded and return ``` {string[0]} ``` if it is an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

```
axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:60231/api/values',
        method: 'post',
        data: qs.stringify(model),
        })
```

Using "qs.stringify" on my model as well as "data" as key. If it is params, the data will be sent as query string.